# CVS Branch in Eclipse History View

Tags: java, eclipse, branch, cvs

I'm on a project where we're using a lot of branches.
The eclipse History tab has columns for Revision, Tags, Author Comment, and Revision Time.
There's no column to indicate the branch a commit is against.
Now I can work this out sometimes by finding which revision a branch was branched from, but this is painfully slow sometimes, and sometimes multiple branches were branched from the same revision.

Is there a way of making eclipse show me a "Branch" column?

Edit: or an alternative plugin that provides a similar view but with the branch for each revision?

I'm using Eclipse 3.5.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know of a specific way in the normal Eclipse history view; this http://versiontree.sourceforge.net may work for you. I am using Eclipse Helios (3.6.0) and the version for 3.4 still works.

Installation is not available through an update site. Just download the JAR and drop it in the Eclipse plugins folder. Restart Eclipse and you should then be able to follow the directions on that site.

Comment: Thanks, I've been wondering about that sort of view also. It does make it easier to determine the branch, but still not as easy as just having an extra column in the History view.